# How to use GeoTools MathTransform?

Tags: java, geometry, geotools, geography

I need to transform points from EPSG:4312 to WGS84 using GeoTools Java library.
But I'm not sure if I use it correctly, also I'm not sure it provides correct results.

See the following code sample:

```
    @Test
    public void testSingle4312ToWGS84() throws FactoryException, TransformException {
        double latitude = 29.0;
        double longitude = -99.0;

        CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4312");
        CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
        MathTransform engine = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCrs, targetCrs, false);

        DirectPosition source = new DirectPosition2D(sourceCrs, longitude, latitude);
        DirectPosition target = new DirectPosition2D(targetCrs);
        engine.transform(source, target);

        System.out.println("x,y=" + target.getCoordinate()[0] + "," + target.getCoordinate()[1]);
    }
```

When running above code I get the following results:

```
x,y=-81.00483829765083,-150.99434404015307
```

Which is wrong, because -150 is not a valid latitude.

When I created the *source* object, I initialized X with longitude and Y with latitude, following the rationale that actually **X is longitude and Y is latitude** (according to the geographic community).
However, if I reverse them:

```
DirectPosition source = new DirectPosition2D(sourceCrs, latitude, longitude);
```

I now get a result that looks more real:

```
x,y=29.003866857343915,-98.99222530180596
```

Of course I have to interpret X as latitude and Y as longitude now.

So, question #1, should we go with the inverse rational treating X as latitude and Y as longitude?

Next, I wanted to validate the result. First, trying to convert the same point using an Oracle SQL SDO function:

```
select sdo_cs.transform (
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4312, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(-99, 29, NULL), NULL, NULL),
8307
) from dual;
```

provides the following result:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(-98.9924748682774, 29.0036029261273, NULL), NULL, NULL)
```

The converted point is similar with the one produced by GeoTools, but there is a difference of ~40 meters.

Next, I tried the transformation offered by this [website](https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/), which provided the same results as Oracle.
I also used Luciad AIXM Viewer, a graphical representation tool for GML, and this also displays my point at the same position computed by Oracle.

So, I have 3 independent tools providing the same result point which is 40 meters away from the one computed by GeoTools.
Question #2, why is Geotools failing? Is Geotools reliable for CRS transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue with axis order you have fallen for a common beginner's problem of assuming that you know what the axis order of a projection is, and in the case of ESPG:4326 that it is fixed.

For example, the following code:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

System.out.println("EPSG:4326 - " + CRS.getAxisOrder(targetCrs));
System.out.println("WGS84 - " + CRS.getAxisOrder(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84));
```

gives this output:

```
EPSG:4326 - NORTH_EAST
WGS84 - EAST_NORTH
```

But if you add the line `Hints.putSystemDefault(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);` the output becomes:

```
EPSG:4326 - EAST_NORTH
WGS84 - EAST_NORTH
```

So, in general you should never rely on a "known" axis order in your code, instead using something like:

```
double latitude = 29.0;
double longitude = -99.0;

CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4312");
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

MathTransform engine = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCrs, targetCrs, false);

DirectPosition2D source;
if (CRS.getAxisOrder(sourceCrs).equals(org.geotools.referencing.CRS.AxisOrder.EAST_NORTH)) {
  source = new DirectPosition2D(sourceCrs, longitude, latitude);
} else {
  source = new DirectPosition2D(sourceCrs, latitude, longitude);
}
DirectPosition target = new DirectPosition2D(targetCrs);
engine.transform(source, target);

if (CRS.getAxisOrder(targetCrs).equals(org.geotools.referencing.CRS.AxisOrder.EAST_NORTH)) {
  System.out.println("lon,lat=" + target.getCoordinate()[0] + "," + target.getCoordinate()[1]);
} else {
  System.out.println("lon,lat=" + target.getCoordinate()[1] + "," + target.getCoordinate()[0]);
}
```

As for the accuracy of the transform that would depend on which referencing module you imported and which CRS definition Oracle are using. With the `gt-epsg-hsql` module loaded I see the same `ToWGS84[601.705, 84.263, 485.227, 4.7354, -1.3145, -5.393, -2.3887]` matrix as the most accurate transform provided in the [EPSG registry](http://epsg.io/4312-1194). If there is an NTv2 transformation available then [adding that to your project](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349062/use-high-precision-to-convert-image-from-one-epsg-defined-crs-to-another) should improve precision.

Comment: Thank you for your educational answer :). When using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: I'm not sure if there is anyway to find out what transformation Oracle use - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/epsg-model-and-spatial-and-graph.htm#SPATL054 is unclear

Comment: When using Oracle Database 12.2.0.1.0 and performing: `select * from cs_srs where srid=4312`, I see there is no TOWGS84 element in WKTEXT, but there is a WKTEXT3D having TOWGS84[577.326, 90.129, 463.919, 5.137, 1.474, 5.297, 2.4232], which is different then gt-epsg-hsql-12.4 (version that I am using). For now I will stick with GeoTools, but it will be hard to explain to the customer that, my transformation is more correct than Oracle.

Comment: You can probably update the transform the Oracle uses but if you are really worried about 10s of metres then you should add the NTv2 transforms for the projection

Comment: 12.4 is pretty old, you will get a more up to date EPSG database with 25.0

Comment: What happens if you try with a point that is actually in Austria (14.87599632 47.24040813)?

Comment: Valid question. My customer was testing Austrian conversion to WGS84 using coordinates from Texas. I know... but I have to support also EPSG:4269 and others and I was blocked by the first issue described. However converting this Austrian point using both Oracle and GeoTools results in a difference of 0.22 meters, which falls in the accepted tolerance. So, I will stick with GeoTools, because I think it will work for real world data. Btw, doing a bit of reverse engineering on Luciad Viewer, I found out this tools is using the same TOWGS84 array as Oracle and this explains their perfect match.

Comment: If the srsName is "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" how would you advise to handle it? I'm asking because I can't find a CRS name that works with CRS.decode(). Alternativly I can "convert" to EPSG:4326 by switching the ordinates. But I'm curious if GeoTools has native support for it.

Comment: That **should** be long/lat always but I would probably check anyway